# possible for directive to run each time when scope changes?

Tags: angularjs

I want to write a directive to for a table `TBODY` to show some text when it is empty. I want to achieve this by writing a directive that detects if the table's `TBODY` has any child TR, if not then show some text.

I do not wish to use `ng-if="model.entries.length == 0"` because I might have a TR in there for creating new entry that won't belong to entries.

The directive I wrote currently only works one time because it only runs once. When entries changes the directive won't run again and therefore the empty text is still showing

```
baseModule.directive('emptyTbody', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (element.find('tr').length == 0) {
                element.addClass('empty');
            } else {
                element.removeClass('empty');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible to write a directive that runs when scope changes like regular angular behavior? Or if this cannot be achieved through a directive, is there any other ways to achieve this?

Here is the Html

```
<tbody empty-tbody>
    <tr ng-if="isCreating()">
        <td>
            <input ng-model="creatingItem.Name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in model.entries" >
        <td>
            <input ng-model="item.Name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a isolate scope and put watch there

Like this

```
baseModule.directive('emptyTbody', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            source: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch("source", function(nv) {
                if (nv) {
                    if (nv.length == 0)
                        element.addClass('empty');
                    else
                        element.removeClass('empty');
                } else
                    element.addClass('empty');
            });

        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<tbody empty-tbody source="model.leps">
```

**EDIT**

If you wanna to use only from element .

You can use anonymous function to watch.

Try like this

```
baseModule.directive('emptyTbody', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return element.find('tr').length;
      }, function(nv) {
         if(nv){
           console.log("Table has data")
         }
         else
           console.log("Table has no data");
      });

    }
  }
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/w3v7uxar/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, i mentioned that I don't want to do this by checking the the model.entries.length. I want to do this by checking if the TBODY has any TR childrens. So i want the directive to run anytime theres a scope change like an ng-if/ng-model/function would. The reason for this is because I have a "creating" TR that doesn't belong to model.entries as you can see in the HTML. I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: actually. I think your response has helped me. Basically you've given me a way to watch when a model changes. I believe that solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. still very new to directives